# problem in installing opencv in python 3.10.6

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I have an old version of mac and I am facing a problem that I want to use the library cv2 inside a code written in python 3.10.6. When I write the command in terminal:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

I get this error:

```
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.6.0.66.tar.gz (90.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [210 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools==59.2.0
        Using cached setuptools-59.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
      Collecting wheel==0.37.0
        Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Collecting cmake>=3.1
        Using cached cmake-3.24.0-py2.py3-none-macosx_10_10_universal2.macosx_10_10_x86_64.macosx_11_0_arm64.macosx_11_0_universal2.whl (77.9 MB)
      Collecting pip
        Using cached pip-22.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
      Collecting scikit-build>=0.13.2
        Using cached scikit_build-0.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.21.2
        Using cached numpy-1.21.2.zip (10.3 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting packaging
        Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
      Collecting distro
        Using cached distro-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
      Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2
        Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [166 lines of output]
            setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10.
              warnings.warn(
            Running from numpy source directory.
            Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
            Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
            Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
            Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
            Cythonizing sources
            blas_opt_info:
            blas_mkl_info:
            customize UnixCCompiler
              libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            blis_info:
              libraries blis not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            openblas_info:
              libraries openblas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            accelerate_info:
              libraries accelerate not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
            Library accelerate was not found. Ignoring
              libraries veclib not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
            Library veclib was not found. Ignoring
              FOUND:
                extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
                extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
                define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      
              FOUND:
                extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
                extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
                define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      
            non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
            lapack_opt_info:
            lapack_mkl_info:
              libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            openblas_lapack_info:
              libraries openblas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            openblas_clapack_info:
              libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
            flame_info:
              libraries flame not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/opt/local/lib']
              NOT AVAILABLE
      
              FOUND:
                extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
                extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
                define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      
            Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
            /private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
              warnings.warn(msg)
            running bdist_wheel
            running build
            running config_cc
            unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
            running config_fc
            unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
            running build_src
            build_src
            building py_modules sources
            creating build
            creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
            creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy
            creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/distutils
            building library "npymath" sources
            Could not locate executable gfortran
            Could not locate executable f95
            Could not locate executable f90
            Could not locate executable f77
            Could not locate executable xlf90
            Could not locate executable xlf
            Could not locate executable ifort
            Could not locate executable ifc
            Could not locate executable g77
            Could not locate executable g95
            Could not locate executable pgfortran
            don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
            creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core
            creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src
            creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath
            conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h
              adding 'build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
            conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
            conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
            None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
            building library "npyrandom" sources
            building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
            creating build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray
            conv_template:> build/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
            building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
                main()
              File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
                json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
              File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
                return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 211, in build_wheel
                return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 197, in _build_with_temp_dir
                self.run_setup()
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
                super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
                exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
              File "setup.py", line 448, in <module>
                setup_package()
              File "setup.py", line 440, in setup_package
                setup(**metadata)
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-install-mwu3ldyu/numpy_154377a2a09e4d8388cc75094c35666d/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
                return old_setup(**new_attr)
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
                return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
                dist.run_commands()
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
                self.run_command(cmd)
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
                self.run_command('build')
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-install-mwu3ldyu/numpy_154377a2a09e4d8388cc75094c35666d/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 61, in run
                old_build.run(self)
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
                self.run_command(cmd_name)
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
                self.distribution.run_command(command)
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-961h78bo/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
                cmd_obj.run()
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-install-mwu3ldyu/numpy_154377a2a09e4d8388cc75094c35666d/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
                self.build_sources()
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-install-mwu3ldyu/numpy_154377a2a09e4d8388cc75094c35666d/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 161, in build_sources
                self.build_extension_sources(ext)
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-install-mwu3ldyu/numpy_154377a2a09e4d8388cc75094c35666d/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 318, in build_extension_sources
                sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
              File "/private/var/folders/66/ytwk5_zd4pz81w7q9fhtz_yh0000gn/T/pip-install-mwu3ldyu/numpy_154377a2a09e4d8388cc75094c35666d/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
                source = func(extension, build_dir)
              File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 434, in generate_config_h
                moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
              File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 44, in check_types
                out = check_types(*a, **kw)
              File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 289, in check_types
                raise SystemError(
            SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
      Failed to build numpy
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

could someone help solving this problem, I spend days to solve this issue. As a note: I have more than one version of python in my laptop, I am not sure if this is the reason.

Comment: Which python versions do you have installed? Is `3.10` the one that you definitely want to use?

Comment: I am using 3.10.6 version of python

Answer (score 1):

First you have to uninstall the both python version.Than,You have to install the python 3.9.10 version from python.org and after installation upgrade your pip and everything will be sort .It is the problem in python 3.10.2 ...This method is working ,i was suffering from same problem in installing the turtle so i did that and error was solved. Make sure you update pip before installing new python and opencv